# Convolutional Neural Networks. No aparecen las imagenes

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, keras

Estoy haciendo el ejercicio de deeplearning( en Jupyter Notebook) de https://github.com/jbagnato/machine-learning/blob/master/Ejercicio_CNN.ipynb
. Lo único que no me funciona esta en las ultimas dos lineas. En donde quiero comparar dos imágenes
filenames = ['ciclismo_0001.jpg', 'golf_0103.jpg' ] con la red neuronal y como respuesta me aparece

ciclismo_0001.jpg ciclismo

golf_0103.jpg     golf

Cuando también me debería aparecer las imágenes y lo que no entiendo es porque no aparecen las imágenes .Lo que aparece entre comillas triples son los resultados que me da el segmento del programa. Gracias de antemano por cualquier tipo de ayuda sobre el tema.

```
from skimage.transform import resize

images=[]
# AQUI ESPECIFICAMOS UNAS IMAGENES
filenames = ['ciclismo_0001.jpg', 'golf_0103.jpg' ]

for filepath in filenames:
    image = plt.imread(filepath,0)
    image_resized = resize(image, (21, 28),anti_aliasing=True,clip=False,preserve_range=True)
    images.append(image_resized)

X = np.array(images, dtype=np.uint8) #convierto de lista a numpy
test_X = X.astype('float32')
test_X = test_X / 255.

predicted_classes = sport_model.predict(test_X)

for i, img_tagged in enumerate(predicted_classes):
    print(filenames[i], deportes[img_tagged.tolist().index(max(img_tagged))])

"""ciclismo_0001.jpg ciclismo
golf_0103.jpg golf"""
```

Comment: No, en este trozo de código no haces ningún plot de ninguna imagen, por lo que no deben aparecer las imágenes.

Comment: Hola Gracias por comentar . Yo Hice todo el ejercicio de https://github.com/jbagnato/machine-learning/blob/master/Ejercicio_CNN.ipynb  y cada segmento dio bien en los resultados no escribi todo el codigo en la pregunta porque era muy largo. Mi consulta es : En todo el codigo del programa para lo  que sirve es para darme como resultado nombres de archivo sin imagenes?. Gracias de antemano  por tu tiempo